# how to correctly assign value to a list in TCL?

Tags: list, foreach, tcl

I have a question about list in tcl, what is the correct way to assign value to a list?

```
set employeeList ""
set TYPEID_3456 8
set TYPEID_9876 6
set TYPEID_6578 7

if {$employeeType=="1"} {
    set employeeList "8"
} elseif {$employeeType=="2"} {
    set employeeList "6 7"
} else {
    prints "failed"
}

foreach employee $employeeList {
    if {$employee==$TYPEID_3456} {
        #do something
    } elseif {$employee==$TYPEID_9876} {
            #do something
    } elseif {$employee==$TYPEID_6578} {
        #do something
    }
}
```

is this a correct way? because it tells me the TYPEID_3456 can not read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote is correct: the string values will be interpreted as a list in the `foreach` command.

However I would write it like this to be clearer about your intentions, and use the [`switch`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/switch.htm) command to be more concise:

```
set employeeList [list]
set TYPEID_3456 8
set TYPEID_9876 6
set TYPEID_6578 7

switch -exact -- $employeeType {
    1 {lappend employeeList 8}
    2 {lappend employeeList 6 7}
    default {puts "failed"}
}

foreach employee $employeeList {
    switch -exact -- $employee {
        $TYPEID_3456 {
            #do something
        }
        $TYPEID_9876 {
            #do something
        }
        $TYPEID_6578 {
            #do something
        }
    }
}
```

Or, create a data structure that combines the `employeeList` and `employeeType`:

```
array set employeeList {
    1 {8}
    2 {6 7}
}

set TYPEID_3456 8
set TYPEID_9876 6
set TYPEID_6578 7

if { ! [info exists employeeList($employeeType)]} {
    puts "no employee list for employee type '$employeeType'"

} else {
    foreach employee $employeeList($employeeType) {
        switch -exact -- $employee {
            $TYPEID_3456 {
                #do something
            }
            $TYPEID_9876 {
                #do something
            }
            $TYPEID_6578 {
                #do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not change the structure of foreach loop, it is a existing set of code and I can not change it. if we code is right, but why it tells TYPEID_3456 can not read?

Comment: According to the code you posted, that should not happen. Is it a scope issue: is TYPEID_3456 a global variable and are you trying to use it in a procedure without declaring it as global?

Comment: @ratzip To be clear, the code you wrote works _as it is presented to us_. It appears to be correct. That it doesn't work for you means that you're leaving out at least one significant detail when writing your question.

Comment: yes, I find the problem, I did not global the TYPEID_3456, thank you you guys!